# Creating buffer for MultiPolygon that covers all its surroundings in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, buffer, polygon-creation, multipart

When I try to use the Buffer tool in QGIS, it only allows me to create buffers in degrees ("grados" in the screenshot below) and it does not give me the option of changing the units (to meters/km/etc..).

What I´m trying to do is to have a 10-meter buffer for each political division. Does anyone know what I can do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The distance parameter in buffer tool is in the units of your coordinate system, so in your case it is in degrees which is bad because one degree at the equator does not equal the same distance as one degree nearer the poles.

You should [reproject](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisreprojectlayer) your data to a coordinate system with meters as units, like one of the [UTM](https://mangomap.com/robertyoung/maps/69585/what-utm-zone-am-i-in-#) zones.

I'm in Sweden so I would use UTM zone 33: https://epsg.io/32633

Comment: Thank you!!! But still I cannot make a buffer of all polygons just one as a whole. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Nice! [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdissolve) them into one polygon then buffer